# Filter comments by Entry Author in the Control Panel

Tags: comments, filter, hook, author

I've been looking up the hooks that can be used with the Comment Module. But I don't think there is one I could use to **filter the list of comments by entry author in the Control Panel**. I'm trying to filter that list so users only see the comments on entries they've added.

Is there any existing **add-ons** that can do this? Or are there any **hooks** I could use to write an add-on myself?

Thanks in advance!
Diederik.

Answer (score 1):

One approach to only show comments on posts that have been authored by the logged in user is to use a conditional comparing `logged_in_member_id` to `author_id`. Do this inside your channel entries tag pair and embed the comment entries if the condition is met. Simplified example:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="blog"}
    <h1>{title}</h1>
    {if logged_in_member_id == author_id}
        <p>You wrote this post, so can see these comments:</p>
        {embed="embeds/_comments"}
    {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: I wasn't really clear about this, sorry. I'm talking about comments listing in the backend...

Comment: Ah, I see. I had assumed front end. For the Control Panel you will probably have to build a custom module. I can't think of an existing tool to do that. PS - You should edit your question to make it clear that you're talking about the Control Panel not the front-end. This will give you a better shot at getting an answer. Plus it will push your question to the forefront again.